# Create a progress bar on the edge of View in React native with animation

Tags: react-native, animation, progress-bar

I want to create a progress bar on the edge of View like the below image with animation.

Thank you for helping me with any design ideas

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code and give a more thorough explanation about what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, dear @BasvanderLinden.I have a player .I want to show current time of sound(seekBar) on top of the edge View and Fill the line(seekbar) when playing audio.how can I create this UI and create animation to fill color?